# Business pack treeview dotvvm - all tree nodes collapse after redirect

Tags: dotvvm

I use business pack treeview component for menu. What I want to archieve is that when I click on item `Chleba` for example, it will redirect me to details of this category and also items `Potraviny` and `Pečivo` should be expanded. Both items must have this css class `bp-state-expanded`. Right now when I am  redirected to details, all items from treeview are collapsed

Below is sample of my category menu.

[image]

`CategoryList` contains all categories which are displayed in treeview.

`CategorySelectedList` contains single object where I clicked.

```
public List<CategoryListDTO> CategoryList { get; set; } = new List<CategoryListDTO>();
public List<CategoryListDTO> CategorySelectedList { get; set; } = new List<CategoryListDTO>();
```

Here is my redirect method to details

```
public void RedirectToCategory()
{
    var details = CategorySelectedList.FirstOrDefault();
    var productId = details.Id;
    var productCategory = details.Name;
    Context.RedirectToRoute(Routes.Product, new { ProductCategory = productCategory, Id = productId });
}
```

Is there a way how I can archieve this?

Comment: We will discuss possible solutions and let you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have implemented auto-expanding of items in `SelectedValues` collection. It will be available in a release coming later this month.